# Solace can't SEND while in WaitingForDNS

Tags: node.js, typescript, solace

I'm trying send a message on a topic queue but the API returns

```
OperationError: Cannot perform operation SEND while in state WaitingForDNS
```

The URL can be pinged and it resolves to an IP address. I feel this message is misleading.
FWIW, I'm using Solace's Javascript API calling it from my Typescript code.

Below is  code snippet. I've tried to remove irrelevant items such as the console logging. In short, it tests for a session already having been created, and if not, creates it using the Solace factory, then sets some event handlers which I think are irrelevant to this item
so I didn't include them. Because I don't catch any errors at connect() time, I presume it connected. Then when I try to send(), it suddenly is still waiting on the DNS. Or, at least, the error implies this.

```
    class TopicPublisher {
    private getSession() {
        if (this.session == null) {
            try {
                this.log('Creating session for url=' + this.hosturl+' vpn='+this.vpn+' username='+this.username);
                this.session = this.solace.SolclientFactory.createSession({
                    // solace.SessionProperties
                    url: this.hosturl,
                    vpnName: this.vpn,
                    userName: this.username,
                    password: this.pass,
                });

                // Set session event handlers
                try {
                    this.session.connect();
                } catch(error : any) {
                    this.log('Could not make connection to existing session. Error: '+error.toString());
                    this.session = null;
                }


            } catch (error: any) {
                this.log(error.toString());
            }

        }
        return this.session;

    }

    public publish(messageContent: any) {
        var solaceMessage = this.getSolaceMessage(messageContent);
        this.log('Publishing message "' + messageContent + '" to topic "' + this.topicName + '"...');
        try {
            // *************************
            // This is where SEND fails 
            // *************************
            this.getSession().send(solaceMessage);
            this.log('Message published.');
        } catch (error: any) {
            this.log(error.toString());
        }

    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An OperationError is thrown when you are attempting to execute a command on the session before it's actually up. What you can do here is only `return this.session` on `session.on(solace.SessionEventCode.UP_NOTICE)`

You can also see more info on this in the [API docs](https://docs.solace.com/API-Developer-Online-Ref-Documentation/js/solace.Session.html#connect) and check out the note in the docs

> Note: Before the session's state transitions to 'connected', a client
> application cannot use the session; any attempt to call functions will
> throw solace.OperationError.